# Get the same arrival rate across models

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a model that I have duplicated and made some adjustments to it. When I run both models with the same fixed seed I don’t get the same results, which I understand because I have other sources of randomness in the model. Regardless, in both models, I am using a source block, such that the arrivals are defined by a rate schedule, the schedule is of type rate, and is provided from the database. Now, I know the following pieces of information:

1. Generally, I can use my own random number generator (RNG) in distributions, for example triangular(5, 10, 25, myRNG), such that Random myRNG = new Random (2)
2. By default, a schedule with “type” rate follows a passion distribution that utilizes the default RNG.
3. At anytime in the model, I can substitute the default RNG with my own by calling setDefaultRandomGenerator(Random r).

The question is: Is it possible to use a fixed seed for the arrival rate to make sure I am getting the same exact input in both models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In anylogic, rates are always equivalent to a poisson distribution with lambda equal to the rate you set,

Intearrival times don't follow any distribution, but using exponential(lambda) in the field is equivalent to using a arrival by rate with a rate of lambda.

But poisson and exponential are closely related, which is why if you use `poisson(1.0/lambda)` in the intearrival time, you have the same average arrivals as if you use `exponential(lambda)`.

It is not possible to set a seed for the arrival rate, and that's why you need to use intearrival times instead in your source

But you need to create a variable first, let's call it rand, of type Random with initial value `new Random(seed)`
where seed is any integer you want (long to be more exact)

then in the intearrival time you need to do:

```
exponential(lambda, 0,rand)
```

This will lead to unique simulation runs, no matter what configuration you have in the AnyLogic experiment

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here regarding probability distributions. First, poisson(1.0/lambda) is not equivalent to exponential(lambda), but they do have the same mean. I think the confusion is coming from the fact that a "Poisson process" follows a Poisson distribution, and Poisson processes are defined by their exponential interarrival times.

Comment: Also, at the beginning when you said "In anylogic, rates are always equivalent to a poisson distribution with lambda equal to the rate you set." They are actually equivalent to an exponential distribution with lambda equal to the rate you set. Was this a typo? And I'd like to add that your answer is a valid solution to the asker's question. That is to say, arrivals defined by rate=lambda is equivalent to arrivals defined by interarrival exponential(lambda, 0, rand).

Comment: @RyanMarizza from the AnyLogic help documentation from the source block: "a Poisson stream of arrivals can be implemented by choosing arrivals with a certain rate, or by specifying the exponentiallydistributed interarrival time"

Comment: and a note that when i say equivalent, i'm really saying that they are closely related and you can mathematically derive the poisson distribution from the exponential... but anyways, this is not the point of this question, I'm just clarifying

Comment: The reason I commented was to warn against using poisson(1.0/lambda) interchangeably with exponential(lambda). They share a mean, and are closely related, but the distributions themselves are wildly different.

Comment: Reinforcing the comments by @RyanMarizza -- the Poisson distribution is a counting distribution, it describes the probabilities associated with getting different numbers of events in one unit of time. The exponential distribution is a continuous distribution associated with how much time elapses between Poisson events. The two distributions are closely related to each other but are describing different characteristics of a Poisson Process.

Comment: ok, i edited the answer to be more accurate

Comment: nevertheless, in AnyLogic using a rate of X is EXACTLY the same from all statistical point of views as using interarrival time with exponential(X)... I'm not sure if you are saying that this is wrong, because it isn't... obviously poisson and exponential are different, but poisson(X) defined as rate of arrivals is definitely equivalent as exponential(X) defined as intearrival times

Comment: You keep saying "equivalent" to describe the relationship between a continuous distribution and a discrete distribution. It might be better (but still technically sloppy) to say they have an inverse relationship since the mean of a Poisson with rate lambda is lambda, while the mean of an exponential with the same lambda is 1/lambda. As a concrete example, if you expect 10 things to happen per minute on average,  then the average amount of time between those occurrences is 1/10 of a minute. Sharing the same lambda != equivalent distributions.

Comment: Thank you @Felipe, what if I have lambda to be different throughout the simulation run, for example from 8:00-11:00 AM lambda = 1 and from 11:00 AM - 3:00 PM lambda = 0 and so on, because now when I use interarrival time, I am not depending on my schedule anymore

Comment: @Duoaa That’s a different question and should be posted separately, not as a comment..

Comment: @pjs I see, because in my question I have already mentioned that I am using a Rate schedule that is provided from the database, but sure, there is no harm in asking that in a separate question.

Comment: @Duoaa Your question was "Is it possible to use a fixed seed for the arrival rate to make sure I am getting the same exact input in both models?"  That's an entirely different question than "How do I generate from a [nonhomogeneous Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process)?" As Benjamin points out in his blog post (linked in a comment), stackoverflow is designed around the principle of one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply set both Source blocks to "Interarrival time" in the "arrivals defined by".

Then, use the same code `poisson(1, myRNG)` in the field, making sure that the `myRNG` RNG uses the same initial seed (i.e.`new Random(1234)`

(the "Rate" setting is the same as using `poission(1)` for interarrival-time)

Comment: It worked :), but earlier when I was using "Rate" I used to get around 9 arriving agents for one simulation run, now with "Interarrival time" I am getting 49 agents.

Comment: sorry, Rate is actually exponentially distributed. See the help where the relation is explained: "Rate — agents are generated at the specified arrival rate (which is equivalent to exponentially distributed interarrival time with mean = 1/rate).". See https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/source.html#parameters

Comment: I see, thank you Benjamin,  but what if I have lambda to be different throughout the simulation run, for example from 8:00-11:00 AM lambda = 1 and from 11:00 AM - 3:00 PM lambda = 0 and so on, because now when I use interarrival time, I am not depending on my schedule anymore

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow