# Using varying lambda with interarrival time while receiving same arrivals across models

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have learned from my previous question “[Get the same arrival rate across models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305552/get-the-same-arrival-rate-across-models/72311533?noredirect=1#comment127754593_72311533)” that for two models with the same arrival rate input, I can get the exact same arrivals generated in both models by setting the source block in both to “Interarrival time” and in the code, use exponential(lambda, 0, rand) where rand is a user-defined random number generator (RNG), for example, Random rand = new Random(1234). If prior to setting the source block to “Interarrival time” I had it set to “Rate Schedule” in which the schedule is of type rate that is provided from the database and in my case the rate (lambda) is not constant, it depends on the time of the day, how can I overcome this when setting the source block to “Interarrival time”?

Comment: I can't help you with anylogic, not being a user of their product, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568982/2166798) may be what you're looking for. I believe anylogic allows you to use Java, in which case the *thinning* technique would be easy to implement if it's not already an anylogic built-in capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to set a seed for the arrival rate, you'll need to use interarrival times instead in your source.

However, since you also need to vary the interarrival time based on the time of day, you should write a function that returns different exponential random variables depending on the time of day and use that as your interarrival times.

Here is how I did that in AnyLogic:

[image: Source block]

[image: function]

And I made a quick plot of how many injections were occurring per hour just to verify that the rates *are* actually changing.

[image: plot]

Comment: This same idea has crossed my mind, I implemented it, but the problem was in the first hours of the model time, I expect no arrivals (lambda = 0), and so even in later hours of the day when the rate > 1, nothing is generated.

Comment: I see how that would cause problems. What you could do is every day as soon as your rate increases above zero, just call source.inject(). This will cause an "extra" agent to be injected not according to the rate schedule you want, but it will also set the next interarrival time and start generating agents. You could  even write some logic to delete that one extra agent immediately after it leaves the source block.

Comment: This is exactly why Peter Lewis invented the thinning technique back in the 1970's. Check out the link in my comment after the question to see how to handle time-varying rates in a statistically valid fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm understanding the question wrong, but interarrival times can these not be transformed to arrival rate, so for example if interarrival time = 2minutes, the arrival rate is 0.5 per minute. If this is the case for your model, you can use in the source block arrivals defined by: a rate schedule (as shown in the figure below.)

[image]

After that in the schedule you can change the different arrival rates, so for example between 00:00 and 01:00 the arrival rate should be 1 as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Comment: I was previously using "Rate schedule" but switched to "interarrival" to be able to use my own RNG, the problem is, in my case, the interarrival time is not constant.

Comment: @Duoaa in the schedule that arrival rate is also not constant, cause it is changing over time. Perhaps you could create a schedule progammaticaly at the start up, based on the parameters of the RNG